# Создание окна и OpenGL контекста в нем

Tags: linux, c, opengl

Приведите пожалуйста простой пример создания окна через XCB и создания в нем контекста OpenGL через EGL.
Если певое у меня легко вышло то со вторым возникли проблемы ибо примеров работы EGL с XCB маловато.

Comment: По opengl вроде бы много информации, нужно или дополнить вопрос деталями, что б знающие linux вопрос заметили, или закрыть. Я до сих пор считал что glVertex и семейства достаточно для opengl. Главное контекст подключить.

Answer (score 0):

пример кода для создания контекста OpenGL через EGL:

```
#include <EGL/egl.h>
#include <EGL/eglext.h>

int main() {
    EGLDisplay display = eglGetDisplay(EGL_DEFAULT_DISPLAY); // Получение дисплея EGL
    EGLint major, minor;
    eglInitialize(display, &major, &minor); // Инициализация EGL
    static const EGLint config_attribs[] = {
        EGL_SURFACE_TYPE, EGL_WINDOW_BIT, // Тип поверхности - оконный тип
        EGL_RED_SIZE, 8, // Количество бит на красный цвет
        EGL_GREEN_SIZE, 8, // Количество бит на зеленый цвет
        EGL_BLUE_SIZE, 8, // Количество бит на синий цвет
        EGL_ALPHA_SIZE, 8, // Количество бит на альфа-канал
        EGL_RENDERABLE_TYPE, EGL_OPENGL_BIT, // Указание на использование OpenGL в качестве рендерера
        EGL_NONE
    };
    EGLConfig config;
    EGLint num_configs;
    eglChooseConfig(display, config_attribs, &config, 1, &num_configs); // Выбор конфигурации EGL
    static const EGLint context_attribs[] = {
        EGL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 3, // Мажорная версия контекста
        EGL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 0, // Минорная версия контекста
        EGL_NONE
    };
    EGLContext context = eglCreateContext(display, config, EGL_NO_CONTEXT, context_attribs); // Создание контекста EGL
    xcb_connection_t *conn = xcb_connect(NULL, NULL); // Подключение к серверу XCB
    const xcb_setup_t *setup = xcb_get_setup(conn);
    xcb_screen_t *screen = xcb_setup_roots_iterator(setup).data; // Получение экрана
    xcb_window_t window = xcb_generate_id(conn); // Генерация идентификатора окна
    uint32_t values[] = {XCB_EVENT_MASK_EXPOSURE};
    xcb_create_window(conn, XCB_COPY_FROM_PARENT, window, screen->root, 0, 0, 640, 480, 0, XCB_WINDOW_CLASS_INPUT_OUTPUT, screen->root_visual, XCB_CW_EVENT_MASK, values); // Создание окна
    xcb_map_window(conn, window); // Отображение окна
    eglBindAPI(EGL_OPENGL_API);
    EGLSurface surface = eglCreateWindowSurface(display, config, window, NULL); // Создание EGL поверхности окна
    eglMakeCurrent(display, surface, surface, context); // Связывание поверхности и контекста EGL
    // Теперь вы можете использовать функции OpenGL здесь
    eglSwapBuffers(display, surface);
    xcb_flush(conn);
    xcb_disconnect(conn); // Отключение от сервера XCB
    return 0;
}
```

**Надеюсь, это поможет вам с решением)**